# How to display multiple row counts with some varying information for one city?

Tags: carto

My table has two rows for the same city, latitude and longitude but there are different counts, office names and office number designations.

For example:

`Raleigh, NC; Long -78.6389, Lat 35.7806; Count 745; Office body shop; Office number 1`

`Raleigh, NC; Long -78.6389, Lat 35.7806; Count 3445; Office glass shop; Office number 2`

I went to map view to display the information and turned on display count, office and office number. When I click the city it only shows one row's information and the other office is missing. What adjustments need to be made to display both offices that share the same location?

I will also need to do this for other locations that share the same location but are designated with different office names and office numbers.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have the same exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a table merge using the city name as the common value. You have more information in the next tutorial http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/merging_data.html